# Is there any way to compare 2 strings with different lengths using strcmp in C

Tags: c

Suppose that I want to compare 24 and 4 as a string. Instead of returning a positive number since 24 is greater than 4 based on their ASCII values, it tries to return a negative value since it only compares the first digits of both strings since they have different string lengths. Is there any way where it compares all the characters in both strings?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char st[100] = "24";
    char st1[100]= "4";

    printf("%d", strcmp(st, st1));
}
```

Comment: Given the strings `"4"` and `"24"`, what would you compare the `4` in the `"24"` string to?  If you want to compare **numbers** with different numbers of digits and not strings, you need to convert the strings to actual numbers.

Comment: It's a function that find out whether two strings are the same. In the case of `"24"` and `"4"` it doesn't look at the rest of `"24"` because there is no need to. Just by looking at the first `char`, it knows that the strings aren't the same.

Comment: I need to use string because what if I have to use a char like I want to compare 2019-4 and 2019-24 (with hyphen)

Comment: Is there any way where it will not disregard the value of the last digit in the first string?

Comment: I don't understand. Please specify the algorithm you want to use to compare strings. What does it mean to compare "all characters in both strings"? You can compare two things at a time - one character with another. How to compare "all characters"? What should the result be? `I want to compare 2019-4 and 2019-24` then convert strings into pair of numbers and compare numbers, isn't that what you want?

Comment: The problem if I make padding to the left, the "space" char has a value in ASCII which will distort the comparison.

Comment: You can padd with `'0'` to the left.

Comment: 24 is not "greater than 4 based on their ASCII values". Each character has its own ASCII value so it doesn't make sense to talk about the ASCII value of a string.

Comment: What I mean when comparing "all characters in both strings", suppose that 24 has an ASCII value of 102 since 2 is "50" and 4 is "52" in ASCII, then 4 has an ASCII value of "52" so 102 > 52. I want it to return a positive number.

Comment: There is no `24` character. `2` has an ascii value and `4` has an ascii value. So you want to sum ascii values of characters in a string and then compare the sums? Are you sure? So `"99990000"` and `"00009999"` will compare equal? Its' easy to do, just `int sumit(char *s) { int r = 0; while (*s) r+=*s; return r; }` and then `return sumit("24") - sumit("4")`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I guess I misunderstood the strcmp() function. Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AndrewHenle commented:

> If you want to compare numbers with different numbers of digits and not strings, you need to convert the strings to actual numbers.

As it is clear from your comments that you want to compare the *numeric value* that is *contained* in the strings, you need to do just that -- convert the strings to actual numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    char st[100] = "24";
    char st1[100]= "4";

    long val, val1;
    char * endptr;

    errno = 0;
    val = strtol( st, &endptr, 10 );
    if ( errno == ERANGE || *endptr != '\0' )
    {
        // error parsing st -- not a number, or additional characters
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    val1 = strtol( st1, &endptr, 10 );
    if ( errno == ERANGE || *endptr != '\0' )
    {
        // error parsing st1 -- not a number, or additional characters
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%ld", val - val1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You *could* just use [atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi), especially if you can guarantee the fields to contain numbers and nothing but numbers within the proper value range (due to having parsed them from the date input you are apparently processing), but I preferred to showcase the more robust, error-checking version.

Answer (score 2):

C standard defines `strcmp()`:

> `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`
>
> The `strcmp()` function shall compare the string pointed to by `s1` to the string pointed to by `s2`.
>   The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type `unsigned char`) that differ in the strings being compared.

**RETURN VALUE**

> Upon completion, `strcmp()` shall return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than `0`, if the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`, respectively.

The spec only states the sign of the return value, not the value itself, so no, with `strcmp()` is not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear.